# Order of automorphism divides order of element

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Question:
>
> Let $a$ belong to a group $G$ and let $\left | a \right |$ be finite. Let $\phi_{a}$ be the automorphism of $G$ given by $\left ( x \right )\phi_{a}=axa^{-1}.$
>
> Show that $\left | \phi_{a} \right |$ divides $\left | a \right |.$
>
> Exhibit an element $a$ from a group for which $1<\left | \phi_{a} \right |<\left | a \right |$

Only **SUBTLE** hint(s).

Comment: That "*subtle* hints" requirment (?) is discouraging and at least I won't be posting any answer, as subtle usually relies heavily on the beholder's eyes, yet I'll tell you one thing (subtle, non-subtle: I can't say) : what you ask to prove is true for **any homomorphism**, and for automorphisms the orders are identical.

Comment: @M.Vinay Thank you, and you're right: I misread the question.

Comment: @Joanpemo However, the result you mention *is* a good way to prove this result. Show (or merely recall) that $\phi_a$ is the homomorphic image of $a$!

Comment: @M.Vinay Indeed so, yet that already implies that some *other* homomorphism must be considered: from $\;G\;$ to $\;\text{Inn}\,(G)\le\text{Aut}\,(G)\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is subtle enough: For the first part, let $n=|a|$ and determine $\phi_a^n$. For the second part, $G$ needs to be non-abelian to have $|\phi_a|>1$, so try working with a familiar small non-abelian group.